# If statement executed no matter what

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to compare two strings in a file separated by comas to another string like so:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G in (files.txt) do ( 
    if "%%G"=="copy" do (
         copy .\a\something.txt .\b

    )
```

No matter what I compare to, the copy is executed. In the file.txt the are only two strings, like so:

string1.txt,string2.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no DO in an IF statement. Start by changing IF statement to

```
    if "%%G"=="copy" copy .\a\something.txt .\b
```